# modules and comodules related to BP_*

Tags: comodules

Let BP be the Brown Peterson spectrum. We know that the category of $BP_* BP$-comodules is an abelian category. Consider the category of $BP_* BP$-comodules, which are finitely presented as $BP_*$-module. Is this also abelain (have kernel and cokernels)?